# Invalid storage class for a function in a macro in GCC

Tags: c, gcc, macros

I have this legacy macro

```
#define ASYNC_FUNCTION(x)                                               \
void x(void) {                                                          \
    static void internal ## x (ASYNCIOCB *);                            \
    ASYNCIOCB *aiocb = AcquireAsyncIOCB();                              \
    CallAsyncNativeFunction_md(aiocb, internal ## x);                   \
}                                                                       \
static void internal ## x (ASYNCIOCB *aiocb)
```

followed by this one

```
#define ASYNC_FUNCTION_START(x)  ASYNC_FUNCTION(x) {
#define ASYNC_FUNCTION_END       ASYNC_resumeThread(); }
```

And their use looks like this:

```
ASYNC_FUNCTION_START(Occasional_function_name)
{
    //actual stuff    
}
ASYNC_FUNCTION_END
```

It compiles fine with cl, but gcc gives

```
invalid storage class for function ‘internalOccasional_function_name’
     static void internal##x (ASYNCIOCB *);    
                 ^
```

I tried to expand them all just to see what it becomes and found nothing broken. I also searched for unclosed curved brackets in the file, and found other macros like this

```
#define Foo_Bar1()  {                                                \
  extern int foo;                                                    \
  int bar = foo;                                                     \
  if (condition) {                                                   \
    Bar_Foo();                                                       \
  }                                                                  \

#define Foo_Bar2()                                                   \
  if (condibar != footion1){                                         \
    AbortAsyncIOCB(aiocb);                                           \
    return;                                                          \
  }                                                                  \
  if (condition) {                                                   \
    Bar_Foo();                                                       \
  }                                                                  \
}
```

No other headers are included, so other than that last macro looking weird, I couldn't find any obvious errors. I'm using cygwin and I'm fairly clueless.

Comment: Can a static function be declared inside another function at all?

Comment: I don't know the exact way, but people say it can http://stackoverflow.com/a/11706921/2792852

Comment: The code isn't mine unfortunately. I could try just removing `static`, but I don't want to see it go mad if it breaks something.

Comment: Just move the last line of the first macro before the `x` function, and get rid of it inside the function. I mean, make the prototype global.

Comment: For the reference, removing `static` did compile, but I don't know how dangerous it might be. As for making it global, @eugene-sh can you please post your idea as an answer?

Comment: It still would have internal linkage, i.e. be only compilation-unit local. Anyway this looks like obfuscated code and will be pretty hard to maintain&debug.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't declare a static function inside of another one.  You need to put the declaration outside of `void(x)`:

```
#define ASYNC_FUNCTION(x)                                               \
static void internal ## x (ASYNCIOCB *);                                \
void x(void) {                                                          \
    ASYNCIOCB *aiocb = AcquireAsyncIOCB();                              \
    CallAsyncNativeFunction_md(aiocb, internal ## x);                   \
}                                                                       \
static void internal ## x (ASYNCIOCB *aiocb)
```

Then, if you run the source through just the preprocessor via `gcc -E`, you'll get something like this (extra spacing added):

```
static void internalOccasional_function_name (ASYNCIOCB *);
void Occasional_function_name(void)
{
    ASYNCIOCB *aiocb = AcquireAsyncIOCB();
    CallAsyncNativeFunction_md(aiocb, internalOccasional_function_name);
}
static void internalOccasional_function_name (ASYNCIOCB *aiocb) 
{
    {
        int a=1;
    }
    ASYNC_resumeThread();
}
```

Comment: I still wonder how it compiled with cl (and for the author of that code).

Comment: "You can't declare a function inside of another one". Er... Yes, you can, of course. Why not? It is just that `static` function declaration is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

In C language local function declarations can optionally include storage class specifier `extern`. That's the only storage class specifier a local function declaration may have. No other storage class specifiers are allowed.

6.7.1/7:

> The declaration of an identifier for a function that has block scope shall have no explicit storage-class specifier other than **extern**.

Comment: *hint, some kernel implementations violates standard (written before standard i guess) i.e static__exittest() in macro module_exit(exit) in module.h